# What is the use of Smarty {foreachelse}?

Tags: html, foreach, smarty

My scenario:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {foreach from=$users item=user}
            <tr>
                <td>{$user.name}</td>
                <td>{$user.email}</td>
            </tr>
        {foreachelse}
            There are no users....
        {/foreach}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now when there are no users I have an ugly table, so I'll add:

```
{if $users|count > 0}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {foreach from=$users item=user}
                <tr>
                    <td>{$user.name}</td>
                    <td>{$user.email}</td>
                </tr>
            {foreachelse}
                There are no users....
            {/foreach}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{else}
    There are no users....
{/if}
```

But now my `{foreachelse}` is useless.

So I delete the `{foreachelse} There are no users....` part and conclude that `{foreachelse}` is useless.

This problem I have in `<table>`, `<ol>`, `<ul>` etc..

Does anyone have a solution so I'm able to use `{foreachelse}`?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why is the method useless just because you can use another method?

Comment: No, because I use `{foreach}` only to create a table or list. And in that cases `{foreachelse}` is useless (or someone know a better solution).

Comment: foreachelse is useful when you want/need to output a row that says there are no rows. Pretty handy for a structure where you must have a table no matter what.

Comment: What @BoltClock says - and when you don't want to show a table when there are no records, you use your approach above. Not sure what the problem is

Comment: @BoltClock So what if I want a table if there are results and (for example) a div for the feedback if there is no result?

Comment: Then don't use foreachelse. Just because the feature is there doesn't mean you're forced to use it, and just because you're not using the feature doesn't make it completely useless. foreachelse may not suit all use cases, but it certainly fits the bill for some (I've given just one obvious example).

Comment: @BoltClock I think this feature is very nice. I am just looking for a solution to use it in my case.

Comment: This is not what foreachelse is intended for. I don't know why you're forcing yourself to use it and insist on calling it useless if you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one row which says there are no users, eg:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {foreach from=$users item=user}
            <tr>
                <td>{$user.name}</td>
                <td>{$user.email}</td>
            </tr>
        {foreachelse}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">There are no users....</td>
            </tr>
        {/foreach}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I can understand it when this is not the desired result.

Sometimes you might use divs in a foreach instead of table or lists contents. Check the smarty documentation on this:
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 1):

`{foreachelse}` is executed when there are no values in the `from` variable. It's a very useful for me and `if-else` condition is not needed. If I use your code then I would put the `{foreachelse}` like this,

```
{foreachelse}
     <tr><td colspan="2" style="color:red">There are no users....</td></tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Not the desired result. Feedback in a table is with headers is realy ugly and confusing.

Comment: Well, in your case you don't have to use `{foreachelse}` part.

Comment: So tell me, when do you use `{foreachelse}` then?